# Finding intersection of pandas data frame index in groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Python and have a data frame with a datetime index, a grouping variable (gvar) and a value variable (x).
I would like to find all the common datetimes between the groups.

I already have a solution using functools, but I am seeking a way to do it using pandas functionalities only (if possible).

```
import functools
import pandas as pd

gvar =  ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B']
x = [100, 200, 100, 200 , 100, 200]
ind = ['2018-01-01','2018-01-02', '2018-01-03', '2018-01-03', '2018-01-04', '2018-01-05' ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'gvar':gvar, 'x': x},  index=pd.to_datetime(ind))

common_time = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: pd.np.intersect1d(x, y), [df[df.gvar == x].index
                                       for x in set(df.gvar)])

common_time
Out[39]: array(['2018-01-03T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df_filtered=df[df.groupby(level=0)['gvar'].transform('size').ge(2)]
print(df_filtered)

           gvar    x
2018-01-03    A  100
2018-01-03    B  200
```

---

```
df_filtered.index.unique()
#DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-03'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a nice compact solution.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
>>> df.reset_index().loc[df['gvar'].reset_index().drop_duplicates().duplicated('index'),'index'].tolist()
```

Returning:

```
[Timestamp('2018-01-03 00:00:00')]
```

And if you need the corresponding groups or values:

```
>>>df[df.index.isin(df.reset_index().loc[df['gvar'].reset_index().drop_duplicates().duplicated('index'),'index'].tolist())]
```

Giving you:

```
           gvar    x
2018-01-03    A  100
2018-01-03    B  200
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have accepted ansev's answer as it is a more compact solution.